# If two languages together cover all words and one is regular, is the other one as well?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

If $L_1$$\subseteq$ $\Sigma^*$, $L_2$$\subseteq$ $\Sigma^*$ , $L_1$ is regular and $L_1$$\cup$ $L_2$ = $\Sigma^*$ then is $L_2$ necessarily regular?

I think that the answer is yes, but I'm not sure on my proof.

The reason that I think that $L_2$ is regular is because surely $L_2$ just accepts all the words in the language that $L_1$ doesn't? So, to me, that suggests that $L_2$ must be regular as well, I just don't know where to begin on a formal proof.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to think: what if, for example, $L_1=\Sigma^*$? What are then the conditions on $L_2$?

Comment: So if $L_1$ = $\Sigma^*$ then $L_2$ must just accept nothing?

Comment: Remember that $L_1$ and $L_2$ can have common elements.

Comment: Of course... So if $L_1$ = $\Sigma^*$ then $L_2$ $\subseteq$ $\Sigma^*$ still... But I don't see that helps me? Do I have to use $L_2$ to produce a non-regular language?

Comment: Well, what happens if you choose a non-regular language for $L_2$? Can you find one s.t. $L_1 \cup L_2 = \Sigma^*$ when $L_1 = \Sigma^*$?

Comment: So what about if $\Sigma$ = {a,b}, so then $L_1$ = $\Sigma^*$. Could we we have the non-regular language for $L_2$ being equal to $a^n$$b^n$?

Comment: Both conditions ($L_2 \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and $L_1 \cup L_2 = \Sigma^*$) seem satisfied, so $L_2 = a^nb^n$ looks good. So: "is $L_2$ necessarily regular"?

Comment: So $L_2$ is not necessarily regular! Thank you for all your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @James Can you answer your own question with the counterexample?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, I will do that now, I wasn't sure whether or not to do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the answer is no.

If $L_1$$\subseteq$ $\Sigma^*$, $L_2$$\subseteq$ $\Sigma^*$ , $L_1$ is regular and $L_1$$\cup$ $L_2$ = $\Sigma^*$ then is $L_2$ is not necessarily regular.

We can prove this through counter-example.

If we let $L_1$ = $\Sigma^*$, then we can choose any non-regular language in $\Sigma$  for $L_2$.

If we take $\Sigma$ = {a,b} and then let $L_2$ = $a^n$$b^n$ (A non-regular language) then  $L_1$$\cup$ $L_2$ = $\Sigma^*$ and $L_2$ is non-regular as required.